# Eventos JavaScript onchange

Tags: javascript

Lo que ocurre es que creo el  elemento input y luego el id , lo que quiero es extraer el valor que introduzco en el input , pasa que cuando quiero hacer la función de evento "onchange" al hacer click pase el dato que quiero ponerlo en un vector, el problema se encuentra que cuando envio el dato del formulario el vector me aparece vacio como que nunca llegaron los datos, quisiera saber cual es mi problema si es algo de la sintaxis u otra cosa ,desde ya gracias

codigo js:

```
var formulario=document.getElementById("form");
var vector=[];
var dato;
function agregar(){
     vector.push(nombre.value);
     
  }

for(var i=0;i<2;i++){

var itemLabel=document.createElement('label');
itemLabel.textContent='Ingrese nombre:';
formulario.appendChild(itemLabel);

var itemInput=document.createElement('input');
 formulario.appendChild(itemInput);

 
 itemInput.id="nombre";
 
 document.getElementById("nombre").onchange=agregar;

}
```

Codigo html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" action="" method="" id="form">
    
    
          <input type="submit">
       
        </form>
       
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Falta el código HTML al que está ligado tu código Javascript. Pulsa en [edit] para agregarlo.

Comment: ya lo agregue ...

Comment: No entiendo mucho tu lógica. ¿Estarias creando un `input` de forma dinámica en un bucle? ¿Le estarías asignando el mismo `id` a ese `input`? ¿Y luego querrías recoger el valor de ese `input` para meterlo en un array? Realmente no logro entender la lógica. ¿Podrías explicarla y justificar por qué procedes de ese modo? Por ejemplo, asignar el mismo `id` a un elemento no es correcto y podría hacer que el código se comporte de forma inesperada.

Comment: Por otra parte, no existe ningún elemento llamado `nombre`, tampoco lo necesitas, podrías por ejemplo hacer esto para agregar al array el valor del `input`: **`vector.push(this.value);`**. Pero me sigue pareciendo una lógica un tanto extraña.

Comment: claro lo que quiero hacer son varios formularios según indique el usuario anteriormente , para hace debo crear los elementos desde javascript para agregarlos al html, claro seria de forma dinamica como escribiste anteriormente

Comment: Tienes que poner **`vector.push(this.value);`** para obtener el valor del input que cambió. No existe en ninguna parte de tu código un elemento `nombre`.

Comment: adentro de la funcion agregar? pero que pongo en el evento:

Answer (score 0):

En tu código hay algunos errores.

1. En la función `agregar()` estás intentando obtener el `value` desde un elemento `nombre` que no existe. En ese contexto puedes usar `this`, que seria cualquier de los  `input` que haya cambiado y que llama en el onchage a la función `agregar()`
2. Al crear el `input` dinámicamente ya tienes una referencia al mismo en la variable `itemInput`. Hay **dos cosas importantes a tener en cuenta ahí**. La primera es que puedes usar directamente a `itemInput` para asignarle la función en el onchange, no necesitas usar `document`, porque no te estás refiriendo al elemento desde fuera, sino que en `itemInput` ya tienes el elemento como tal. La segunda es que no es correcto asignarle un mismo `id` a distintos elementos. Dado que el bucle crea varios input por tanto no es correcto asignarles el mismo `id`. Tampoco necesitas asignar un `id` porque puedes asignar el listener de otra forma.

```js
var formulario = document.getElementById("form");
var vector = [];
var dato;

function agregar() {
  vector.push(this.value);
  console.log(vector);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

  var itemLabel = document.createElement('label');
  itemLabel.textContent = 'Ingrese nombre:';
  formulario.appendChild(itemLabel);

  var itemInput = document.createElement('input');
  formulario.appendChild(itemInput);
  itemInput.onchange = agregar;
}
```

```html
<form action="" action="" method="" id="form">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: se guardan los datos dentro del vector antes que se envien pero como haria para mantenerlos guardados despues que se envien , cuando pongo enviar el vector se vacia.

Comment: @J.Guillen para eso tendrías que evitar que el formulario se envíe con preventDefault o de otro modo. Eso no viene como problema en tu pregunta. El problema era que los datos no se estaban recogiendo en el vector. Si ha surgido un problema nuevo es mejor que abras otra pregunta para plantearlo, dando más detalles sobre el contexto, por ejemplo, una vez que se envía el formulario, ¿qué debe ocurrir? Hay otra cosa que deberías controlar también en tus input, por ejemplo, ¿está permitido que se escriba varias veces en cada input? ¿Qué debería ocurrir en ese caso? ....

Comment: ... ¿Se debería sustituir el valor anterior?  ¿Se debería guardar como dato nuevo en el vector? etc... Si está permitido escribir una sola vez, deberás programar código para que el input se bloquee una vez se haya escrito en él la primera vez... Como ves, hay otros muchos detalles a resolver.

Comment: gracias si me ayudaste mucho ahora formulo otra pregunta mejor

Comment: @J.Guillen recuerda marcar como respuesta con el check